# Pick up data from union of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I merged two databases by union following that:

```
select model,price 
from pc 
union 
select model,price
from laptop
```

It's working
But when i use select statement to pick data. It so not working.
Here is my code

```
select model
from (  select model,price 
         from pc 
     union 
     select model,price
     from laptop
    )
```

Error happens at the last operator ")".
I don't know why it errors and how to solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set **Alias** Name for the Select

Try like this

```
Select model
From ( Select model,price 
       From pc 
       Union 
       Select model,price
       From laptop
     ) AS t
```

Or:

```
With tbl as 
  (    Select model,price 
       From pc 
       Union 
       Select model,price
       From laptop
  )
Select model from tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select model
from (  select model,price 
     from pc 
     union 
     select model,price
       from laptop
  ) as t
```

it may be because u are missing table alias.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With tab as (select model,price 
from pc  
union 
select model,price
from laptop)
select model from tab;
```

or

```
select model
from (  select model,price 
     from pc 
 union 
 select model,price
 from laptop
) tab
```